# Effects are shown in 'Compositing' but won't render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm pretty new and just following some tutorial. Got that problem I can't get solved even after reading docs.

I did a 30sec movie (rendered to .png). Now I put this into Blenders Video Editor and switch to Compositing (activating 'Use Nodes'). There is the problem: no matter which filter I'm adding (Lens Distortion, VHS) it just won't render. It shows in the preview ('Viewer' Node) but it won't render.

Using Blender 3.6 because on Blender 4 there's no 'Denoiser' for my Debian system.

[image: Overview]

Comment: maybe make sure that you have not loaded a movie or series of images in the Video Sequencer?

Comment: @moonboots I opened Blender -> Video Editing -> Shift + a -> Image/Sequence and choose the png's to add. Was that wrong? Couldn't figure out any other way to add the clip.

Comment: If you have a movie or image in the video sequencer this is what will be rendered, not your 3d scene, so remove it, it's better to open a new file to deal with the video sequencer imho, in order to not confuse with the 3d scene render, is it your problem here?

Comment: Thank you very much. That was exactly my problem. There was no point in adding the files into the sequencer. After opening the 'Video Editor' directly go to 'Compositing' to add the movie (png's) into the 'Movie Clip' Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have loaded a video or image sequence in your *Video Sequencer*, this is what will be rendered, not your 3D view + *Compositor*. To render your 3D view remove the video strip or disable the *Sequencer* option in the *Output* panel > *Post Processing*. For everything that has to do with video editing it's generally better to open a new file that will be dedicated to this task imho.